# How to Randomly disable box collider in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

i have two simple 3d cube objects a,b. so my task is to randomly  disable box collider one of the object every time game start.

my initial thought is randomly generate Boolean and if  it is false then disable the box collider.

Comment: So, how did you go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add you cube's to array and use `Random.Range(0, yourArray.Length)` to get index of the cube which should be deactivated. In your case it will be some overhead but this solution will be work for different cube`s count in the future.
In code it will looks like:

```
// You can serialize this array and add cubes from Inspector in Editor
// or add script with this code to the parent gameobject 
// and use GetComponentsInChildren<BoxCollider>() to get all colliders
var cubes = new BoxCollider[2] {firstCube, secondCube};
var cubeToDeactivationIndex = Random.Range(0, cubes.Length);
cubes[cubeToDeactivationIndex].enabled = false;
```

About your second question. If I understand correctly, implementation will be next:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

// Interface need to provide limited API
// without open references to gameobject and transform of the object
public interface ICollidable
{
    event Action<ICollidable> OnCollided;
    int HierarchyIndex { get; }
    void DisableCollider();
}

// This component you should add to the object which will collide with player
public class CollidableObject : MonoBehaviour, ICollidable
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private Collider _objectCollider;

    public event Action<ICollidable> OnCollided;

    public int HierarchyIndex => transform.GetSiblingIndex();

    private void Start()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(_objectCollider);
    }

    //Here you can use your own logic how to detect collision
    //I written it as example
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        
        if (collision.transform.CompareTag("Player")) {
            OnCollided?.Invoke(this);
        }
    }

    public void DisableCollider()
    {
        _objectCollider.enabled = false;
    }
}

// This component should be on the parent gameobject for your ` 
// collidable objects. As alternative you can serialize array
// and add all collidable objects from the Inspector but in that 
// case signature of the array should be CollidableObject[] 
// because Unity can`t serialize interfaces 
public class RamdomizedActivitySwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ICollidable[] _collidableObjects;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _collidableObjects = GetComponentsInChildren<ICollidable>(true);

        foreach (var collidable in _collidableObjects)
        {
            collidable.OnCollided += DisableObjectWhenMatch;
        }
    }

    private void DisableObjectWhenMatch(ICollidable collidedObject)
    {
        var randomIndex = Random.Range(0, _collidableObjects.Length);

        if (randomIndex == collidedObject.HierarchyIndex) {
            collidedObject.DisableCollider();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: yes it works can you help me little more  so now game starts it randomly disable one of the game object box colider ,  now i want it make little differently i want when player hits any of the child objects and if the random value matches the index of that child object then disable the box colider if child object doesnot colide with player not disable colider.

Comment: @MrAntor so, you can create component which will send index  of the object in hierarchy when it’s trigger with player. Sorry I can’t run IDE and create example, when I will have a electricity i’ll send you how I see it.

Comment: @MrAntor I edited my answer according to your second question.